# Two sets with the same geometric and arithmetic means

Tags: arithmetic-functions

There are two sets A and B with equal geometric mean and arithmetic mean. Each element of both sets is odd integer greater than 1. A = B ? Order of elements isn't important.

Comment: @Ikki By my definition of a *set* they are the same

Comment: If the sets $A,B$ can be of different sizes, this is not immediately obvious.

Comment: It should be made clear: If $A(S),G(S)$ are the arithmetic mean and geometric mean of a set $S$, is one looking for unequal sets $X,Y$ for which the two equations $A(X)=A(Y)$ and $G(X)=G(Y)$ should hold? Or on the other hand are all four of $A(X),A(Y),G(X),G(Y)$ to be equal? Probably the former, as if all four are equal then each "set" has only one element and it's trivial. Also make clear whether the two sets are to have the same size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there another constraint about cardinality? As it stands an obvious counterexample is $A = \{3\}, B = \{3,3\}$.

Comment: But $A=B$ in your example :D

Comment: The cardinality of these $A,B$ is both one, and in fact $A=B$ also. So this is not a counterexample to the question of the OP. If the question were in terms of multisets, OK, but it wasn't.